# How to disable Explore By Touch on Jelly-Bean while accessibility is on?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have created an accessible keyboard for the blind, that works on finger gestures.
But now, with the Jelly-Bean accessibility, Explore By Touch is "stealing" all the gestures and the keyboard isn't working.

Is there a way to disable Explore By Touch from the keyboard when it's on, while TalkBack is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two fingers to enable normal gesture. You could use this to go to the settings and disable the accessibility.

Comment: Thanks, But I need the TalkBack to work and the Explore By Touch to be disabled (or to bypass it)

Comment: The reason is that I need the sound to be heard, but the user should still be able to make gestures on the screen.

Comment: Why this is marked as accepted answer is beyond me. I think disabling Explore By Touch altogether programmatically from within an app is impossible (shame on Google for that) but there seems to be a possible hack in this answer: (the code would need to be readapted to this particular case) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018252/android-override-talkback-gestures#answer-18351172

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an emulator, you can scroll a list by clicking on the bottom item and pressing Space. This will allow you to navigate through the various settings.

To keep TalkBack on, but disable Explore by Touch:

1. Open the Settings application;
2. Scroll down to and open the Accessibility settings;
3. Select the TalkBack item;
4. Press the Settings button at the bottom of the TalkBack activity;
5. Scroll down to the "Explore by touch" option and uncheck this.

You now have the various items being spoken, but not explore by touch.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not possible with JB. Any way, I need it to be automatic when my app is working, and to work back after it closed

Comment: Can I stop "Explore by touch" in specific view in android programmatically?